# '.class.' error in java

Tags: java, c++

I tried a problem which worked fine on C++; here is the C++ implementation.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int t;
char str[1000100];
char num[1010];
cin>>t;
while(t--)
{
    cin>>num;
    cin>>str;
    int a=strlen(str);
    int b=strlen(num);
    int x=0;
    int flag=0;
    int m=0;
    for(int j=0;j<2*b;j++)
    {
        if(m==b)
        {
        flag=1;
        m--;
        }
        if(m==0)
        {
        flag=0;

        }



        num[j]=num[m];
        if(flag==0)
        m++;
        if(flag==1)
        m--;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        if(x==2*b)
            x=0;
        if((str[i]-(num[x]-'0'))<97)
        str[i]=char(str[i]-(num[x]-'0')+26);
         else
         str[i]=char(str[i]-(num[x]-'0'));
        x++;



     }
     cout<<str<<endl;
    //cout<<num;
}
return 0;
  }
```

Here is my Java implementation.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class sngmsg
{
public static void main(String[] s)
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int t;
    /*char[] str;
    str = new char[1000100];
    char[] num=new char[1010];*/
    String str;
    String num;
    char[] num1=new char[1010];
    char[] str1=new char[1000100];
    t=sc.nextInt();
    for(int l=0;l<t;l++)
    {

        num=sc.next();
        str=sc.nextLine();
        int a=str.length();
        for(int c=0;c<a;c++)
            str1[c]=str.charAt(c);
    int b=num.length();
    int x=0;
    int flag=0;
    int m=0;
    for(int j=0;j<2*b;j++)
    {
        if(m==b)
        {
        flag=1;
        m--;
        }
        if(m==0)
        {
        flag=0;

        }



        num1[j]=num.charAt(m);
        if(flag==0)
        m++;
        if(flag==1)
        m--;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
    {
        if(x==2*b)
        x=0;
        if(int(str1[i])-(num1[x])<97)
        str1[i]=char(int(str1[i])-num1[x])+26);
        else
        str1[i]=char(str1[i]-(num1[x]-'0'));
        x++;



    }

    }
}
}
```

In the section

```
if(int(str1[i])-(num1[x])<97)
str1[i]=char(int(str1[i])-num1[x])+26);
else
str1[i]=char(str1[i]-(num1[x]-'0'));
x++;
```

it is giving an error:

```
unexpected type
required:value
found: class
'.class' expected
; expected
```

and similar errors in these lines.
Any help?

Answer (score 4):

it should be

```
if((int)(str1[i])-(int)(num1[x])<97)
```

cast operator should have () over them like (int) 1 and (char) 'a' instead of int(1) or char('a')

Comment: the error in first line got fixed,but same error in line 2

Comment: @techriften: note my comment, you must fix each primitive cast to use parentheses.

Comment: @techriften you should fix all of your casts operators.

Comment: The code is error free,but output is wrong...viz for input
1
132
efg
output should be dce
but after entering 132
it outputs KML
i am using 
for(int i=0;i<a;i++)
                    System.out.print(str1[i]);

Comment: @techriften I would suggest you do some debugging with stepper first. This kind of bug should be really easy to find with a stepper

Answer (score 3):

`int` and `char` aren't functions, but are primitives.

```
str1[i]=char(int(str1[i])-num1[x])+26)
```

You're trying to use `int` as a function. What do you expect from it?

Answer (score 2):

Usualy, you will have a public class with your main method. It seems that you are compiling your class and you are not able to execute it. Do this to solve your problem:

1 - Create a file with your class name, example "MyClass.java"

2 - Your class declaration needs to be public:

```
public class MyClass {
    // your code here
}
```

3 - Place your main method inside the created class:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        // your code here
    }
}
```

4 - Compile it (javac MyClass.java)

5 - Execute it: java MyClass

Your code seems to have some problems too. If you want to cast some primitive or reference type, you need to put the desired type inside parenthesis. Something like:

```
// a char
char c = 'a';

// casting that char to an integer
int i = (int) c;
```

Let me know if it worked.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a package name at the start of the file. Also the class should be public.

```
package something.somethingelse;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class sngmsg{
```